# Reciprocal Lattice and Fourier Transforms

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform

In David Tong's lecture(Application Of Quantum Mechanics) [image]

the second line of Fourier transform the integration over  x ∈ R^3 is replaced by a summation over r ∈ Λ, together with a integration over Wigner-Seitz cell. I do not understand this step. I will be grateful if someone clarify this step.

Answer (score 2):

By translating the Wigner-Seiz cell along the lattice vectors you fill the whole space. He's using that to split up the integral 
$$  \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} = \int_{\bigcup_i \text{cell}_i} = \sum_{\vec r \in \Lambda} \int_\Gamma $$